# Value at 0 cannot be converted to JSON Object

Tags: android, arrays, sharedpreferences, android-json

I am reading String data from `SharedPreference`. The format of my String is

```
[{
    "name": "sdf",
    "phone": "2356235623",
    "no_people": "2"
}]
```

I want to read all `JSONobjects`  present in this `JSONArray`. So I am converting this String to JSON Array as

```
String tempData = addqueuetemp.getString("tempdata", "");
JSONArray cacheTemp=new JSONArray(tempData);
```

Now I am parsing this JSON Array as

```
 JSONArray cacheTemp=new JSONArray(tempQueue);
        for(int i=0;i<cacheTempQueue.length();i++){
            JSONObject tempObject=cacheTemp.getJSONObject(i);
            CurrentStatusEntry tempEntry=new CurrentStatusEntry();
            tempEntry.setName(tempObject.getString("name");
            current.add(tempEntry);
            adapter = new QueueAdapter(current, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

But I am getting error as

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"name":"sdf","phone":"2356235623","no_people":"2"} at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

How to resolve this ?

Comment: What is `cacheTempQueue`?

Comment: Sorry its cacheTemp only

Comment: your code is setting adapter to your recyclerview repetatively in your loop you can move that code outside your for loop

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(result.toString());
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(obj1);
JSONObject dataObj = new JSONObject();
dataObj.put("Data", jsonArray);
JSONArray Jarray = obj.getJSONArray("value");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
JSONArray cacheTemp=new JSONArray(tempQueue);
    for(int i=0;i<cacheTemp.length();i++){
        JSONObject tempObject=cacheTemp.getJSONObject(i);
        CurrentStatusEntry tempEntry=new CurrentStatusEntry();
        tempEntry.setName(tempObject.getString("name");
        current.add(tempEntry);
        adapter = new QueueAdapter(current, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cacheTemp` JSONArray in for loop in place of `cacheTempQueue` and put your setAdateper code to outside loop.

```
JSONArray cacheTemp=new JSONArray(tempQueue);
for(int i=0;i<cacheTemp.length();i++){
        JSONObject tempObject=cacheTemp.getJSONObject(i);
        CurrentStatusEntry tempEntry=new CurrentStatusEntry();
        tempEntry.setName(tempObject.getString("name");
        current.add(tempEntry);
}  

adapter = new QueueAdapter(current, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```